# How to check if a Active Directory server is up and running using .Net?

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

Before trying to query the AD server I would like to check if it is alive and kicking. 
Looks like a trivial thing, but I haven´t found anything to elucidate this.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just try to get the current domain context associated with the running user:

```
try {
    var domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
    /* Whatever i need from the domain */
} catch(ActiveDirectoryOperationException ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot contact AD Server");
}
```

---

If you want to connect to another domain you can try:

```
try {
    var domain = Domain.GetDomain(
        new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "mydomain.local"));
    /* Whatever i need from the domain */
} catch(ActiveDirectoryOperationException ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot contact AD Server");
}
```

Comment: That's only going to work if the machine running the code is actually logged into that domain (which doesn't have to be the case).

Comment: I was trying to avoid try/catch constructs, but that do the trick!

Comment: #get the current domain: I get an exception "Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."

Should my pc join a domain?